# AC current gain of an emitter follower configuration with a Darlington transistor and a source resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis, darlington

We're using the book *Electronic Devices and Circuit Theory* by Boylestad for our circuits class and are currently on Darlington transistors.

I'm trying to solve the current gain of a circuit with an internal resistance at the source and thought about using the two-port systems approach.

Specifically, this formula.
[image: Equation]

However, the book derives an equation for the current gain without load and internal resistance which is this:

[image: Equation2]

I got confused because we were taught that the voltage and current gains have opposite signs. Since the voltage gain is approximately equal to 1, I don't understand if I can really use this equation.

The current gain in the Darlington section is positive but for a normal emitter follower, it is negative. I really need help to confirm what equation to use for this scenario.

This is the circuit that I want to solve:
[image: Circuit]

Comment: Only inverting amplifiers have opposite signs

Comment: In your diagram, I cannot identify the parts Ri, Rs, Rb.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 are you talking about the signs of the voltage and current gain?

Comment: @LvW Rb can be thought of as R1 || R2. For Rs, are you talking about the internal source resistance? Then it is Rg. Is Ri the input impedance or a specific resistor?

Comment: Yes voltage gain sign is negative for inverting amps only.   But the gain Av is asymmetrical for large swing